# Drools: Comparing same type of objects in drools decision table

Tags: java, drools, decision-tree, rule-engine

I'm new to the Drools. I have a list of Persons in the database and would like to compare the current person(The person who is logged in) with the list of the persons in the database and give the points to each person. For that, I'm trying to iterate over the list of persons and inserting the current person and the person from the list to the `KieSession` and want to compare these two same type of objects in the drools decision table and couldn't find a way to do that. As per my example,
currentPerson: Person("Male", "married") and
person1: Person("Female", "married")

I would like to compare these 2 same types of objects and give the points like if the currentPerson `gender` matches with the person1 `gender` then set the `10 points` to the person1 and if the currentPerson `gender and marital` status matches then want to give `20 points` to the person1 like that for all the persons would like to give the points. For that I'm trying to get the two same types of objects in the decision table condition like `$p1:Patient $p2:Patient` and comparing objects like `$p1.gender==$p2.gender` then it always throwing the `java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot find KieModule: org.default:artifact:1.0.0` error. I tried a couple of ways to achieve this, but couldn't solve this.
Could you please suggest to me the way we could achieve this?

**My bean class:**

```
public class Person {
    private String gender;
    private String isMarried;
    private int points;

    public Patient(String gender, String isMarried) {
        this.gender = gender;
        this.isMarried = isMarried;
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public String getIsMarried() {
        return isMarried;
    }

    public void setIsMarried(String isMarried) {
        this.isMarried = isMarried;
    }

    public int getPoints() {
        return points;
    }

    public void setPoints(int points) {
        this.points = points;
    }
}
```

**My Test class:**

```
import org.kie.api.KieServices;
import org.kie.api.builder.KieBuilder;
import org.kie.api.builder.KieFileSystem;
import org.kie.api.builder.KieRepository;
import org.kie.api.builder.ReleaseId;
import org.kie.api.io.Resource;
import org.kie.api.runtime.KieContainer;
import org.kie.api.runtime.KieSession;
import org.kie.internal.io.ResourceFactory;
import org.tgen.drools.model.Person;

public class PersonsComparisonTest {
    private static KieSession getKieSession(Resource dt) {
        KieServices kieServices = KieServices.Factory.get();
        KieFileSystem kieFileSystem = kieServices.newKieFileSystem()
                .write(dt);

        KieBuilder kieBuilder = kieServices.newKieBuilder(kieFileSystem)
                .buildAll();

        KieRepository kieRepository = kieServices.getRepository();

        ReleaseId krDefaultReleaseId = kieRepository.getDefaultReleaseId();

        KieContainer kieContainer = kieServices.newKieContainer(krDefaultReleaseId);

        KieSession ksession = kieContainer.newKieSession();

        return ksession;
    }

    public static final void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            Resource resource = ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource("rules/persons-rules.xls", PersonsComparisonTest.class);
            KieSession kSession = getKieSession(resource);

            Person Person1 = new Person("FeMale", "Yes");

            Person Person = new Person("FeMale", "Yes");

            kSession.insert(Person);
            kSession.insert(Person1);
            kSession.fireAllRules();

            System.out.println("Person =>"+Person.getPoints());
            System.out.println("Person1 =>"+Person1.getPoints());

        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Decision table:**
[image]

Same example working with one object with static data comparison in the decision table. I am inserting only one object into the `KieSession` in this example.

[image]

Comment: Please post what you actually attempted, not a description of it. Your error indicates you're trying to load a kmodule out of a Maven repository and however you've configured your project means that it's unable to locate it. (Either you didn't configure it properly for your private artifactory instance, you didn't publish the artifact correctly, or you're not actually trying to do anything with Maven but set up your project incorrectly.)

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas, Updated the decision table with the java code. could you please check it?